# PostgreSQL default extension setting values in `.control` files?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-extensions

I've seen some PostgreSQL extension examples that use the `.control` file to provide defaults for the extension's settings.  This seems to be a remnant from a time in which extension settings *had* to be provided in the `.control` file for them to be valid to Postgres at all.  My question is: Has putting the extension settings in the `.control` file ever been a required or recommended practice?

I don't see anything in the current [`pg_extension`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/catalog-pg-extension.html) or [`pg_available_extension_versions`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/view-pg-available-extension-versions.html) catalogs that would suggest such a practice.

**Edit 2022-01-08:** My question wasn't sufficiently clear. I was specifically talking above about run-time configuration settings (such as can be set and get via `current_setting()` and `set_config()`). I was not referring to *control file parameters*, which are [neatly described](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend-extensions.html#id-1.8.3.20.11) in the official documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the adage goes, “a couple of years in the laboratory can often save a few hours in the library”. But, when it comes to programming, wasting my own and others' time on stackexchange.com can often save a 5-minute experiment.

I ran the experiment. It is not even possible to add settings of the type `extension_name.setting_name` to the `.control` file. I don't know where I picked up the impression that this was ever possible. I must have mismatched some different fragments of the documentation in my head at some point.

Anyhow, apologies for wasting the time of those who paid attention to my crappy question, [@laurenz-albe](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/176905/laurenz-albe) in particular.

Worst thing: after running the experiment, I finally did recall that I already ran the experiment once before. ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

You didn't look at [the PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend-extensions.html#id-1.8.3.20.11). You *need* a `.control` file for an extension:

> The `CREATE EXTENSION` command relies on a control file for each extension, which must be named the same as the extension with a suffix of `.control`, and must be placed in the installation's `SHAREDIR/extension` directory.

Comment: I apologize. My question was insufficiently clear. I was _not_ talking about _control file parameters_, as you linked to, but to run-time configuration settings.

I've edited my question to be more clear.

To salvage my ego: I did read the documentation, enough so that my public PL/pgSQL extension count is 7 (all of them _with_ a `.control` file ): https://pgxn.org/user/bigsmoke

Comment: I don't think that a parameter *can* be permanently set in a control file (other than with `ALTER DATABASE`). Could you edit the question and show an example of what you mean?

Comment: I since found out that my question was crappy to begin with and answered it myself.

Comment: By the way: my question was not about this, but if you ever find yourself wanting to treat DB (role) settings as unalterable, my [`pg_safer_settings` extension](https://github.com/bigsmoke/pg_safer_settings) has a `pg_db_setting(text, regrole)` function as an example of how to do precisely this.